# Stuck creating a custom css style directive

Tags: angularjs

For an only visual editor I'm trying to create a new directive that writes a CSS style. I'm stuck at trying to get the directive to update when a checkbox is clicked to make the background-color property transparent.

Here's my (non-working) directive:

```
myApp.directive('customstyle', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var bgColor;
      scope.$watch(attrs.myTransparent, function (value) {
        if (value) {
          bgColor = 'transparent';
        } else {
          bgColor = attrs.myBgcolor;
        }
        updateStyle();
      }, true);

      function updateStyle() {
        var htmlText = '<style>.' + attrs.myClass + '{';
        htmlText += 'background-color: ' + bgColor + ';';
        htmlText += "}</style>";
        element.replaceWith(htmlText);
      }
      updateStyle();
  }
}
});
```

and html element:

```
<customstyle my-class="examplediv" my-transparent="settings.Window.Transparent" my-bgcolor="settings.Window.BackgroundColor"></customstyle>
```

Here's a jsfiddle of the situation: http://jsfiddle.net/psinke/jYQc6/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using the directive directly on the element you want to change, it's easier to do and to maintain.

HTML:

```
<div class="examplediv customstyle" 
     my-transparent="settings.Window.Transparent" 
     my-bgcolor="{{settings.Window.BackgroundColor}}">
</div>
```

Note: Use `{{settings.Window.BackgroundColor}}` to pass the property's value and not a String.

Directive:

```
myApp.directive('customstyle', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {          
           scope.$watch(attrs.myTransparent, function (value) {     
             element.css('background-color', (value ? 'transparent' : attrs.myBgcolor));            
           });                      
        }
    }
});
```

Note: Use `element.css()` to change CSS properties directly on the element.

**jsFiddler**: http://jsfiddle.net/jYQc6/8/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. On the page I will be using this on, the style will be applied to an unknown number of items in a list, so setting the css properties on every item didn't seem like the right way to go here. 

I did manage to get it working. Turned out that I had to parse the checkbox value to a boolean to get it to work. And I didn't replace the element, but change the html inside it. I'm still not sure if this is the best way to do this. Got some more learning to do I guess. Here's the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/psinke/YJxR9/

Comment: @Peter, $observe will always return a string, so instead of `if (parseBool(myBool)) {` you could simply do this: `if(myBool == "true") {`.  (The ng-model will only use values `true` and `false` for the checkbox, so there is no need to look for other possible boolean values.)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and using bmleite's solution solved it. I had a custom element with a custom attribute very similar to the one above, and changing the directive to be applied on a regular DIV instead of the custom attribute fixed it for me.

In my solution I also have the following line of code right after the element has been modified:

```
  $compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

Remember to inject the $compile service in the directive function declaration:

```
  myApp.directive('directiveName', function ($compile) { ...
```

Thanks for a great post!