# Change the textbox text color on change of data inside the text box

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a textbox like

```
<input type="textbox"ng-model="data" ng-change="change_color(data)">
```

and a function like

```
$scope.change_color = function(data){

};
```

I do not have an ID for the textbox. But i need to change the color.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly create your own directive (instead of using ng-change) that will change the color when some data changes. This could possibly point you in the right direction: [Stuck creating a custom css style directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318249/angularjs-stuck-creating-a-custom-css-style-directive)

Comment: I am using this textbox inside 2 ng-repeats. So if i define a directive all the textboxes will change the color right ? 
OR can i create dynamic id for this textbox ?