# custom directive function not working angularjs

Tags: angularjs, apply, directive

I have this piece of code , but when the user writes the color in the input, the background color of the new element is suposed to change but is not working, what am I doing wrong?

```
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
         <input type="text" ng-model="color" placeholder="Enter a color" />
         <hello-world/>
   </div>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

      mainApp.directive('helloWorld', function() {
         return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    template: '<p style="background-color:{{color}}">Hello World',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind('click', function() {
        elem.css('background-color', 'white');
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.color = "white";
        });
      });
      elem.bind('mouseover', function() {
        elem.css('cursor', 'pointer');
      });
    }
  };
});
 </script>
```

Comment: You should probably close the `<p>` tag, eg `Hello World</p>`

Comment: here's a similar SO post on [creating a custom css style directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318249/stuck-creating-a-custom-css-style-directive)

Comment: Works fine for me (I used "red" for the click so you could see the change) ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/0Get13WBrQMy5PuFO4oP?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Close your template tag and delete the inline style from there.
Also you should use elem.on() instead elem.bind()

```js
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

      mainApp.directive('helloWorld', function() {
         return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    template: '<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a color" ng-model="color"/><p>Hello World</p>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.color = elem.find('input').val();
      scope.$watch('color', function(newVal, oldVal){
        if(oldVal === newVal) return;
    
        elem.find('p').addClass(scope.color +'');
        
      });
      elem.on('mouseover', function() {
        elem.find('input').css('cursor', 'pointer');
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
  }
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
  <html ng-app="mainApp">
    <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
      </head>
    <body>
      <hello-world></hello-world>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Please for the example type 'red' or 'blue'.

Comment: Where's the `<input>`? I figured that was essential to OP's app

Comment: You can test this just clicking in the blue button 'Run code snippet' at the bottom of my code.